# Is the Bramhamuhurta timing different for mumbai and delhi?

Tags: rituals, panchang

Bramhamuhurta time is same pan India?
What shall one do in Bramhamuhurta?

Comment: it should be different as sunrise timings are different....

Answer (score 1):

Brahma muhartha varies wrt sunrise timings. There is a small time delta between sunrise timings between Mumbai and Delhi. So, It varies a bit.

Brahma muhurtha kala starts everyday at ~3.75 naligas before suryodhaya and ends at ~2.5 naligas after suryodhaya.

Assume, if sunrise is at 6am IST, then brahma muhurta starts at ~4:25am IST and ends at ~7am IST.

Brahma muhurtha is considered to be an auspicious time as per hindu panchangam.

During Brahma muhurtha, One can perform spiritual activities like yajnam, vedhabhayasa, upakarma, nadhabhyasa, yoga, surya namaskaram, any vidhyabhyasa related activities, etc. One can get more benefits.

Waking up before Bhrama muhurtha and perform all our nitya karmanushta makes our life beautiful and successful.

It is believed that one can neutralize the effect of tridhosa(vaadha, pitha, kabha) by waking up before bhrama muhurtha. It helps us to maintain a good health and mind.